# What does "unable to read unknown load command 0x26" means in Xcode 3.2 on Lion?

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb, osx-lion

My project at work debugged under 10.6/Xcode 3.2.5 works fine but at home the same project run under Lion/Xcode 3.2.5 tosses dozens of these

```
unable to read unknown load command 0x26
```

messages in the debugger. Any ideas on what I can do to determine what GDB is complaining about? It still "seems" to work, but I have no idea what might be missing or wrong.

Note this is a regular OSX app, not iOS.

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about. Do you have a small, self-contained, example? Or even a list of the steps you take that lead to the message that disturbs you?

Comment: And Xcode 3 is not supported on Lion.

Comment: I (xcode 3.2.5, OSX 10.6.6) just started getting this message (alternating with 0x25), about twenty times at launch, and then get `Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages` hundreds of times (I'm trying to load data into sqlite, which may account for the number)...nothing changed other than updating my device to iOS5 (yes, I know yours is not iOS)

Comment: Xcode 3 doesn't install on Lion but if you already have it does work. Subsequent to asking this question (which I never figured out) I no longer needed to use Xcode 3. Still be nice to know what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The message comes from [bfd/mach-o.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/gdb/gdb-967/src/bfd/mach-o.c):

```
switch (command->type)
{
    case BFD_MACH_O_LC_SEGMENT:
        if (bfd_mach_o_scan_read_segment_32 (abfd, command) != 0)
            return -1;
        break;
    .....
    default:
        fprintf (stderr, "unable to read unknown load command 0x%lx\n",
            (unsigned long) command->type);
        break;
}
```

The warning says that BFD cannot recognize the Mach-O section load command it has encountered.

Looking at [bfd/mach-o.h](http://opensource.apple.com/source/cxxfilt/cxxfilt-9/cxxfilt/bfd/mach-o.h?txt) where known load commands are described, we find that commands there range from **0x1 to 0x18**, yet nothing beyond.

Mac OS X (Lion) defines load constants in /usr/include/mach-o/loader.h (available if you've installed XCode), from **0x1 to 0x27**. Therefore, the most logical explanation to seeing the **warnings for load commands > 0x18** appears to be the lack of the said codes in BFD's own header.

Also, for follow-ups consider looking at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/tarantool/+bug/1018356